# Google cloud vision updates afftects my prediction

Tags: google-cloud-vision

i have non code question about google vision release related issue i am sorry for this but other forms of support are not allowed in my gmail that's why i am asking this question here my apologies for that.

my question is when ever google updates their google vision there is some changes in ocr response which affects my spacy,automl and all nlp related models which i trained for different purpose so i choose given feature={'model':'legacy'} which i came to know from google vision docuement pages

but google says in there documentation page they will also update their legacy model also but i can't retrain model with new ocr response so there any way to use the current legacy model foreever

https://cloud.google.com/vision/docs/release-notes

[image: google vision]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, the model will no longer be available after August 20, 2022 as mentioned in the [release notes](https://cloud.google.com/vision/docs/release-notes). The only workaround for this is to adjust your models based on the changes of Google Vision. You still have ample time to apply changes bit by bit until the said date so you won't encounter breakages on your production environment.

Also another thing to note is code updates happen frequently and often involve libraries and code from products across Google, and are not just limited to Google Vision. I suggest to monitor the release notes from time to time to be updated on the changes moving forward.